# How to convert a text bibliography into bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a large bibliography (200+ references) in text form (in IEEE style) and I want to convert all of it into bibtex. Are there any tools available to do this?

The text is in this form:-

```
[6] Ganglia, 2011. http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/ (last accessed on 27/12/2011) 
[7] M. Massie et al., “The ganglia distributed monitoring system: design, implementation, and experience”, Parallel Computing 30: 817–840, 2004. 
[8] Nagios, 2011. http://www.nagios.org/ (last accessed on 27/12/2011) 
[9] Spanoudakis G, Kloukinas C. MahbubK.,“The SERENITY Runtime Monitoring Framework, In Security and Dependability for Ambient Intelligence”, In Security and Dependability for Ambient Intelligence, (eds) Spanoudakis G., Mana A., Kokolakis S., Advances in Information Security Series, Springer, ISBN-978-0-387-88775-3, pp. 213-238, 2009 
[10] Foster H., Spanoudakis G., "Advanced Service Monitoring Configurations with SLA Decomposition and Selection", 26th ACM Symposium Applied Computing – Track on Service Oriented Architecture and Programming, March 2011
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [cb2Bib](http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-overview.php):

> The cb2Bib is a free, open source, and multiplatform application for rapidly extracting unformatted, or unstandardized bibliographic references from email alerts, journal Web pages, and PDF files.

Or for other online bibliography parsers just google: http://www.google.com/search?q=bibliography+parser

Comment: I've tried to use it but it doesn't work for me. It just recognises  one reference at a time, which defeats the purpose.